# Simulate winkey + D with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a webpage and I need to implement a button somewhere in the HTML that simulates the pressing of keys **winkey + D** to show the desktop.

I looked for some solution on the web but none of them was clear for me.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Should not be possible.

Comment: Not possible. Win+D is a OS level command, you cannot issue it from a web page. You can at best try to capture it and respond to it but I'm not sure that even then it would get to the page (unless programmatically sent, but then you wouldn't be getting the OS response)

Comment: That would be a massive security issue, so as already stated, it's very much not allowed

Comment: oh that's sad...and is there any other way to let the user to access the desktop?

Comment: @ambdere - Yes. Let **them** press Win+D.

Comment: Not only should any actual answer directly be transferred into a bug report for the respective browser, it would also only work on windows. On my Linux desktop I don't have that shortcut. Worse: I could have configured it to do something different. Don't know about macOS, but it probably won't support it either.

Comment: @ambdere You have to separate code running *in a browser* to code that affects the OS. The browser isolates almost all interactions. You get whatever the browser allows, e.g. you can get stuff like notifications or access tot he audio channel but not anything in any way unrestricted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually the user will not have a physical keyboard

Comment: @ambdere then use a virtual one? As in, explain them how to get to the one built into Windows. Or explain how to click on the "show desktop" button.

Comment: Cross-site possibly related: https://superuser.com/questions/545826/is-it-possible-to-set-keyboard-shortcuts-on-a-webpage

Comment: Imagine it _was_ possible. What about other keyboard shortcuts? Win+L locks the computer until you retype your password, for example. Do you want a random web page to have permissions to do that?

Comment: @mbojko or just do `Ctrl + Win + D` -> `Ctrl + Win + Left Arrow` -> `Win + 1` -> repeat. This will create new virtual desktop and launch a new copy of the first application pinned to the taskbar on each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. You can't issue keystrokes to the user's computer, for obvious security reasons.

*(You might be able to using ActiveX on a truly obsolete version of IE, such as IE8 or maybe IE9, only after getting permission from the user to run untrusted code, but...)*